# GStreamer add probe with playbin

Tags: gstreamer

The following code adds a callback when each frame is displayed and it's working well:

```
pipeline = gst_parse_launch("filesrc location=/path ! decodebin ! autovideosink", &error);

video_sink = gst_bin_get_by_interface(GST_BIN(pipeline), GST_TYPE_VIDEO_OVERLAY);

GstPad *pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(video_sink, "sink");

gst_pad_add_probe(pad, GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BUFFER, (GstPadProbeCallback)cb_have_data, data, NULL);
```

The following code adds the same callback but it's never been called:

```
pipeline = gst_parse_launch("playbin uri=file:///path", &error);

video_sink = gst_bin_get_by_interface(GST_BIN(pipeline), GST_TYPE_VIDEO_OVERLAY);

GstPad *pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(video_sink, "sink");

gst_pad_add_probe(pad, GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BUFFER, (GstPadProbeCallback)cb_have_data, data, NULL);
```

Any idea why and how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

playbin has no input pads and no output pads, so you can't put a
probe, as a probe has to go on a pad.

However, there is a get-video-pad action signal you can run on
playbin, which it's possible to attach a probe to.